# Add X Close Button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

I'm new in `WPF` and I need to make a button (X) to simulate the `X` button in the form. First I set `WindowStyle="None"`. Then make a `Rectangle`:

```
<Rectangle Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="482,4,0,0" Name="x_btn" Stroke="#00000000" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="17" MouseEnter="x_btn_MouseEnter" MouseLeftButtonUp="x_btn_MouseLeftButtonUp">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Red%20Crescent;component/Images/x_btn.png" />
    </Rectangle.Fill>            
</Rectangle>
```

After this I want to change the `Background Image` OnMousEnter event behind code:

```
private void x_btn_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{           
}

private void x_btn_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Please help as fast as you can.

**Note:** I tried to use a `Button` but it's leave a border and i don't want that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case it is better to use the `Style` for the `Button`, and use the [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747393.aspx) instead of the `Image`. To properly implement the function of closing, it is better to implement it through a `DependencyProperty` and set the value directly in `Style`.

*Example*:

```
<Window x:Class="CloseButtonHelp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CloseButtonHelp"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Our style for the ToggleButton -->
    <Style x:Key="ToggleButtonWindowClose" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <!-- Here you can set the initial properties for the control --> 
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />

        <!-- Template needs to completely re-writing the standard control -->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Grid>
                        <!-- Then responsible for the content. In our case it did not really need, because it is set Path -->
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />      
                        <!-- Our Path. Shows a cross -->                       
                        <Path x:Name="CloseWindow" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" ToolTip="Close window" Width="18" Height="17" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#2D2D2D" Data="F1 M 26.9166,22.1667L 37.9999,33.25L 49.0832,22.1668L 53.8332,26.9168L 42.7499,38L 53.8332,49.0834L 49.0833,53.8334L 37.9999,42.75L 26.9166,53.8334L 22.1666,49.0833L 33.25,38L 22.1667,26.9167L 26.9166,22.1667 Z " />
                    </Grid>

                    <!-- Trigger fires on the property --> 
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <!-- Here change the color when the mouse cursor -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="CloseWindow" Property="Fill" Value="#C10000" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <!-- Use ToggleButton, because it has a property IsChecked, accessible through the style -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="local:WindowBehaviours.Close" Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <!-- Set the our style by key --->
    <ToggleButton Name="CloseButton" Style="{StaticResource ToggleButtonWindowClose}" />
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Listing of `WindowBehaviorsClass`:

```
public static class WindowBehaviours
{
    // Closing window
    public static void SetClose(DependencyObject target, bool value)
    {
        target.SetValue(CloseProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CloseProperty =
                                              DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Close",
                                              typeof(bool),
                                              typeof(WindowBehaviours),
                                              new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnClose));

    private static void OnClose(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue))
        {
            Window window = GetWindow(sender);

            if (window != null)
            {
                window.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    private static Window GetWindow(DependencyObject sender)
    {
        Window window = null;

        if (sender is Window)
        {
            window = (Window)sender;
        }

        if (window == null)
        {
            window = Window.GetWindow(sender);
        }

        return window;
    }
}
```

For more information see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx).

Comment: thanks for this code .. but can you describe the xaml code when you use tamplate ... because i'm new in wpf

Comment: Please see my edit. For a better understanding of the styles, study the relevant sources (MSDN, WPF books), because to explain everything in one answer is not real.

Comment: thanks for the description ... but i got a question if you don't mind ... how can I create a separated style file and just add to the form

because i had a big program and alot of controls

Comment: You can add styles to file App.xaml or add them to the `ResourceDictionary`. Dictionaries may be several, but they have some limitations that need to have in mind. [MSDN Link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903952(v=vs.95).aspx) and [MSDN Link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa348820.aspx).

Comment: Only downside is that the `IsMouseOver` only triggers whenever your mouse is over the rendered *X*. So empty space between the rendering doesn't trigger the `IsMouseOver`.